# Getting "unable to fetch mapping. do you have indices matching the pattern"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to configure Kibana/Elasticsearch to my application and having an issue. The error I am getting is:

"unable to fetch mapping. do you have indices matching the pattern", although I have an indice with the name "twitter", as you can see on the image below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I match the index? I'm really stuck here. Thank you!

When I try fetch the data from the twitter index, I also get a response:
[image]

Comment: try unchecking 'Use event times to create index names` as your index name does'nt contain any timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should uncheck `Use event times to create index names`. As index name mentioned by you 'twitter' is not a time based index.

As per a tutorial:

> In elasticsearch it is common to store time-based events in multiple indexes to facilitate search and allow for memory optimization. With one index per day, you could then have a naming pattern for the indexes like twitter-2015.01.15, twitter-2015.01.26, and so on. If you store your data like that you should mark the “Use event times to create index names” checkbox.